# How to query for multiple entries in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a customer database and i'm looking to run a query to find any barcode that was used more than once in a day and output just the barcode... So for example if barcode #1 was scanned 3 times on a specific date it will show 3 transactions in the database all with the barcode #1...  Here is a basic query I have now searching by date...

```
Select *
FROM            Customers
WHERE        (dtCreated BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-12-10 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-12-11 00:00:00', 102)) AND (sBarcode = '1')
```

Instead of searching for barcode 1, i'd like to know ANY barcodes (sBarcode) that was scanned more than once on 12/10/12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select barcode, count(barcode) as cnt from table_name where date = desired_date group by barcode HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)

Comment: This is close, however it says invalid column name for 'cnt'

Comment: HAVING        (COUNT(*) > 1) and it's correct.  If you edit your post I can give you credit for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the last AND statement?

EDIT: ok. You have to group by barcode, agregating on each day. That’s all. Something like:

```
SELECT *
WHERE (dtCreated BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-12-10 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-12-11 00:00:00', 102))
GROUP BY dtID, dtCreated
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: No, that will return ALL customers created on the 10th. I'm looking for duplicate barcode creations.

Comment: I stole the HAVING        (COUNT(*) > 1) from yours and used TwTw and Rohit query.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Count(barcode) counter
FROM  Customers
WHERE  (dtCreated BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-12-10 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-12-11 00:00:00', 102)) AND (sBarcode = '1')
group by barcode
having (COUNT(barcode) >= 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
select sbarcode
from customers
where cast(dtCreated as date) = '2012-12-10'
group by sbarcode
having count(*) > 1
```

If you wanted the count, then you would include `, count(*)` on the `select` line.